# Webpack module federation - don't cache remoteEntry.js?

Tags: webpack, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation

I was wondering - how could i prevent the `remoteEntry.js` file from being cached? When it's cached, if the MFE it points to had deployed again, it won't contain the references to the most up-to-date assets (if they contain a hash)